# UI Image crashes Unity on play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 3D game in Unity.

I want to have an image slowly fill up to make the cooldown of a skill visible for the player. Fortunately the UI image can do exactly that.

Unfortunately the UI image causes the engine to crash when I click play. The generic message "Unity stopped working" shows up too.

I created it by going to GameObject>UI>Image. Then I filled in the Sprite and the main camera. I did nothing else.

Removing the Canvas, Image and EventSystem (Which spawn when creating a UI image) fixes the crash.

Am I doing something wrong? I am very new to Unity.

EDIT: It turns out something in my code IS doing something to the image. However, I never in my code specify anything towards the image. I am using GUI elements though. Could that be the problem?

EDIT2: When running the Unity Debugger it gives me the error `Couldn't set project path to: C:\Users\[MYNAME]\Documents\CellGame\Assets`

I don't know what this means, as everything else is able to load from my assets

EDIT3: That doesn't seem to be the problem at all. What really is the problem is a line I'm calling. I'm going to try to figure out what in that line is causing trouble.

EDIT4: It turned out that there is a problem in my code. When I start my game, for some reason it detects that my player has no health, and goes to the Game Over UI. I had set this to just be the main menu UI, and when it toggles the main menu UI it also reloads the scene. Reloading the scene caused the crash, presumably.

Comment: Are there any error messages visible in Unity's output window or in your IDE after the game crashed? Those might tell you where the error occured.

Comment: No, the whole engine crashes. I don't get a red error. That would've been easy to solve. The problem lies in that Unity closes. Showing "Unity stopped working"

Comment: I see. Try debugging the code and set a breakpoint in the method that works with the image. If you execute one line at a time then you might find the exact line where it crashes, and you could post the surrounding code so people might spot errors.

Comment: have you at all got more than 1 EventSystem?

Comment: I'm not doing any code with the UI image. All I'm doing is putting it into a level.

I only have that 1 event system that spawns with the image. I just tried opening a new scene, creating a UI image and clicking play. That worked fine. Could any code that has nothing to do with the image, cause it to crash? It turns out something in my code IS doing something to the image. However, I never in my code specify anything towards the image. I am using GUI elements though. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my script had a bug, where it would reload the scene as soon as I pressed play. With the UI image in my scene it caused Unity to crash.

I'm not sure why it crashed.